# New Phone - Google location not syncing/sharing to desktop

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, google-maps, location-services, google-location-history

I've just got a new phone (Oneplus 3 from old Samsung S4), and I'm having issues with location in Google Maps - I'm trying to share my location with family (via G+ app), but overall I'm seeing some odd behaviour.

If I go to Google Maps on my **device**, my location is correct.

If I go to Google Maps on my **desktop machine**, my location is wrong (out of date from the time at which I swapped mobile devices)

My G+ location is also refusing to update - showing the out of date location on my desktop, and on the G+ app on my device putting a red dot for me in the *correct current* location but with the text of '*old location* 19h ago'.

Stuff I've tried:

- Check location sharing is on (both pinpoint and city) in G+
- Check location is on in Google Maps 'Google location settings'
- Check location history is on in Google Maps
- Logging out of Google Maps (on device) and logging back in again
- Closing Google Maps (and G+) apps on my device
- Check correct device enabled on Location History (via Google Maps)
- Check location is correct in Google Maps (on device)
- Check I'm signed in on the same account with device, G+ and Maps (I only have one)
- Try Android device finder from desktop (it is correct!)
- Try 'Your Timeline' >> 'Today' in Google Maps on desktop (it is correct!)
- Turning device off and on again (multiple times)

I'm running OxygenOS (3.2.5), with Marshmallow (6.0.1)

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this fixed via the Google maps forums. Nothing exciting, some horrible caching going on requiring a bit of resync. 
see: https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/maps/1t32l4OC9Mo/RkLr1hV3AAAJ
 for fix. Just providing an answer for anyone encountering this issue!